# Which app is issuing a "Synchronization successful" popup?

Tags: popup

Every now and then I get a "Synchronization successful" box overlaid on top of whatever app I'm running at the moment, including fullscreen apps such as games or Netflix. (So to clarify, it's not a drop-down notification).

I do have a quite a lot of apps, and some of these do some kind of frequent "synchronization" (e.g. UberSync for Facebook, Sms Backup+, etc.). I've gone through their options several times and I couldn't find any obvious option.

So my questions are:

- is anyone else getting this? is the culprit well known?
- is there some way to figure out which app is issuing this overlay, short of selectively disabling them until it disappears?

I'm running Android 4.3 on a Nexus 4 phone but I've had this problem on 4.2 as well.

Comment: Well, the question by nature is very broad. This app could be from any app; may be from something you never expect. Can you [edit] the question and add a screenshot please?

Comment: I'll see if I can do it. It's a bit unpredictable and it doesn't last long, so it's not that straightforward.

Comment: That should be a specific API call. Perhaps you can try to connect the phone to your pc and read the logs?